# How to get from Rzeszów to Lviv?

Tags: poland, ukraine

What are my options to find a connection between Rzeszów and Lviv?

Is there a website that lists all Poland->Ukraine buses, like bus.com.ua does for Ukraine->Poland? I couldn't find the list of buses in Internet, and I'd like to check them **before** going there.

Is there a direct connection, or I need to go to Przemyśl first?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by best? CHeapest? That could be hitchhiking, or walking? Fastest? Safest? Only bus?

Comment: There are too many questions in one.  Can you separate them?